# .htaccess conditional redirect https to http

Tags: html, .htaccess, http, https, rackspace-cloud

I'm trying to make all https requested to my site route to http EXCEPT for anything at /shop

Using the following code in my .htaccess but it's not working:

```
#redirect all https traffic to http, unless it is pointed at /shop
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop/?.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Hosted on rackspace cloud sites.

Other code in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Shop rewrite rule + remove trailing slash
RewriteRule     ^shop\/(.*)/$                   shop/$1             [R=301,L]
RewriteRule     ^shop\/([A-Za-z0-9-/]+)$        shop.php?shop=$1        [NC,L,QSA]

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
```

Comment: Provide some details on what's not working. For which URL it's not working?

Comment: URL is a client URL so I cannot share it. But going to the https://www.mydomain.com is not redirecting to http://www.mydomain.com as expected.

Comment: Are there more rules in this .htaccess? What is location of this .htaccess?

Comment: Is there a .htaccess inside `/shop/` also?